# EclipseLink JPA @ElementCollection Map with compound key -- error on remove

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an `Entity` that has a `Map` field mapped as an embedded collection:

```
@Entity
public class PhysicalTp implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id @Column(name="PTP_ID")
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name="IUT_PTP_TRANSMISSION_PARAMETER",
        joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="TMP_PTP_ID", referencedColumnName="PTP_ID") })
    @Column(name="TMP_VALUE")
    private Map<TransmissionParameter,String> transmissionParameters;
    ...
}
```

The key `TransmissionParameter` is an embedded entity that consists of one basic and one FK field:

```
@Embeddable
public class TransmissionParameter implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(name="TMP_NAME",nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="TMP_CLR_ID",nullable=false)
    private CatLayerRate layerRate;
    ... (hashCode, equals, getters, setters, etc...)
}
```

`CatLayerRate` is a simple dictionary entity:

```
@Entity
public class CatLayerRate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id @Column(name="CLR_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="CLR_DESC")
    private String desc;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(name="CLR_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String name;
    ... (hashCode, equals, getters, setters)
}
```

All the mappings works well except removing entity. When I try to remove any `PhysicalTp` instance Eclipselink throws an exception:

```
Exception Description: A NullPointerException was thrown while extracting a value from the instance variable [null] in the object [PhysicalTp].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AggregateObjectMapping[null]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(PhysicalTp --> [DatabaseTable(IUT_PHYSICAL_TP)])
```

P.S. I can not map `TransmissionParameter` as a `@OneToMany` entity because it is used by various entities and for every entity it must be mapped to it's own table.

EclipseLink 2.5.1.

Salu2,
Antón

UPD: full stacktrace (reproduced with other entities)

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-69] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException was thrown while extracting a value from the instance variable [null] in the object [eclipselink.bugs.TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug$MainEntity].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AggregateObjectMapping[null]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(eclipselink.bugs.TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug$MainEntity --> [DatabaseTable(TESTEMBEDDEDMAPKEYBUG$MAINENTITY)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at eclipselink.bugs.TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug.testEmbeddedMapKeyBug(TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-69] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException was thrown while extracting a value from the instance variable [null] in the object [eclipselink.bugs.TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug$MainEntity].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AggregateObjectMapping[null]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(eclipselink.bugs.TestEmbeddedMapKeyBug$MainEntity --> [DatabaseTable(TESTEMBEDDEDMAPKEYBUG$MAINENTITY)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.nullPointerWhileGettingValueThruInstanceVariableAccessor(DescriptorException.java:1277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(DatabaseMapping.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.getRealAttributeValueFromObject(DatabaseMapping.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AggregateObjectMapping.earlyPreDelete(AggregateObjectMapping.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:76)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Are there nulls in your map, or is the map itself null on the object you are removing?  Can you post the stack trace to show what code might be hitting the NPE?

Comment: No, there are no nulls. Operations persist/read/update work well, only fails the remove. It seems to be a bug in EclipseLink. If I remove `@ManyToOne` in `@Embeddable` object and change field to `Long layerRateId` the remove works. I found workaround: use "DELETE" query instead of `em.remove()`.